Power App form dropdown populated from SharePoint list successfully gets its default set, but the form submit doesn't commit to the source
I've used Monitor to check behind the scenes. Dropdown options are coming from a SharePoint list.
Form:
Form4_1
Gallery:
Gallery1_1
Dropdown:
Dropdown11
Datacard Default:
Gallery1_1.Selected.InputID
Dropdown Default:
ThisItem.InputID
Datacard Update:
Dropdown11.Selected.InputID
When selecting an item in the gallery, the dropdown correctly sets its default value. When selecting a different value in the dropdown, it doesn't commit to the SharePoint list in the Update.
In Monitor, I can see the patch DataOperation showing both the original and changed values. If I test using Notify(Dropdown11.Selected.InputID) in the OnSelect of the submit button, it correctly shows the selected value.
I have other forms and dropdowns working just fine using the same pattern.

what is the column/data type of SharePoint list column?

It is text. Strangely, other fields following the same pattern on the form don't have this issue when they are dropdowns. I've also completely deleted and rebuilt the dropdown and no change.

Bump. Anyone experience this before? I've been working on other parts of the app in the meantime.
